# Eclipse Android App Zoom In Code WebView

Tags: android, eclipse, webview, apk

I'm very new to developing android apps. I've edited this app I found, which was open source and have got it working to a good extent. There's some code that isn't being used at all (Like the preferences menu) but I haven't removed that as I simply don't want to mess it up. Anyway, when I view the website it's zoomed in.. I've researched the problem and found a few ways to fix it, but none have worked. The app files can be downloaded at this link: http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/504860/App-zip.html

Thanks for any help!

Comment: what specific problem do you have? Post some code.  You'll get far better answers if you show you've worked on the problem and tried to solve it rather than simply cry for help with no details.

Comment: Sorry, good point. I'm trying to get the zoom feature to work. I've tried to add this: webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); in the Dashboard.java file, on line 3 below.

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); 
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
  getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
  

  WebView engine = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);

This didn't work, and I have tried other ways but to no avail.

Comment: Just some procedural stuff on this site....   If you preface your code with 4 spaces, it's set aside, formatted and highlighted for easier reading.  Also, when you say "it didn't work" give us a clue as to what didn't work, what error messages you got, etc.  That will make it much easier to help solve problems.

Answer (score 0):

Now, here's where the answer comes in.

You get the settings for your webview before you instantiate it. You need something  like:

```
void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);  // do this first

    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.yourwebviewid); // either this or
```

either the above to tie the Java object to an xml object
or create a view and add it to some parent

```
    View parent = (View)findViewById(R.id.yourparent_layout_for_webview); // this
    WebView webView = new WebView();
    parent.add(webView);



    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the tips, and helping me out! As I have said before, I'm very new to apps.. If you could just possibly tell me which file/line I should put the first code.